# How can one use variables in JAVADOC comments?

Tags: java, javadoc

I wish to refer to a particular URL in JAVADOC comments in a project. However, I know that the URL may change in the near future. So, I was looking for a functionality that allows one to use a single variable in place of this URL throughout the project. So that if needed, it can easily be changed, but I could not find one.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I might be missing something, but once the documentation is generated, it is static, so any change to the variable would require running `javap` again - hence you may as well make the change in the documentation itself.  I think this is the case when using @value which sorta does what you want, but needs the variable to be in the code

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149667/javadoc-custom-tags)?

Comment: Well yes. I'm not too sure its correct usage either. :p

Comment: @fge no. didn't see that

Answer (score 14):

By looking into javadoc specification [doc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_documentation.htm) I see this tag : `{@value}`

> Displays the value of a constant, which must be a static field.

So if you create a class for example `DocLinksHolder` and declare static fields there, then you can refer to them in javadoc.

```
{@value DocLinksHolder#fieldName}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven, you can use its filtering feature.

With this in your pom :

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Maven will find all string which match ${something} and replace them with values coming from your pom.

For example, you can put

```
/**
 * URL is ${url}.
 */
```

and in your pom :

```
<properties>
  <url>myUrl.com</url>
</properties>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you end up with filtered Java source files instead of Javadoc files?

Comment: In this case, yes. It depends on what you put in the filtering markup `<directory>src/main/java</directory>`