# Javadoc source code tagging

Tags: java, javadoc

How to classify (by specific predefined tags/keywords) my Java source code by JavaDoc?

I'd like to specify in my JavaDoc comments one or more tags/keywords in order to classify a java class/method. The document site generated by javadoc tool should display the tags/keywords and allow to browse them i.e. return for each tag/keyword the list of classes/methods that was tagged with it.

Is there any custom tag to achieve it?

Thanks in advance,

Marco Delato

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is custom tag, which would provide such functionality. You need to write your own doclet (refer to [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html) for more information on how to write one) and, probably, your own [custom tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149667/javadoc-custom-tags)).